# cannot execute binary file centos?

Tags: centos

I am using centos 6.9 and want to install xampp. But when I run the command on the terminal it showing error i.e. cannot execute binary file. So, How can I fix this problem and successfully install xampp ? Please help me.

```
chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-7.0.22-0-installer.run
./xampp-linux-x64-7.0.22-0-installer.run
```

after this command it showing

```
bash: ./xampp-linux-x64-7.0.22-0-installer.run: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: Please don't use images for text. Copy the text instead.

Comment: Try `file` then `ldd` on the `xampp-linux-x64-7.0.22-installer.run` executable and edit your question to give the outputs (four spaces before each line).

Comment: can you tell me where is the problem ?@C-Otto

Comment: Images are frowned upon on this site.

Comment: This can occur if you attempt to run an x86-64 executable on a 32-bit platform (or vice versa).  You can check it here and download appropriate version of xampp https://www.question-defense.com/2008/11/28/how-to-verify-a-centos-linux-server-is-32-bit-or-64-bit

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running the install (binary) with a lesser privileged user. You'll have to use root user for modifying SELinux settings as such:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t '/<install-location>(/.*)/?'
restorecon -R -v /<install-location>/
```